# How to transfer data between widgets in TkInter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am making a program with a GUI. I want the text entered in an Entry widget to be displayed in a Label widget, once a button has been clicked. So far the only that appears once the button is pressed is:

> (PY_VAR0 + PY_VAR1)^PYVAR2

This is the code for the whole program, I am using a class as a frame layout. The code for this can also be provided if it is needed, but I'm assuming it's not relevant.

```
import math
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

a_input = ParamIn(app, "Please enter A:")
a_input.pack()

b_input = ParamIn(app, "Please enter B:")
b_input.pack()

n_input = ParamIn(app, "Please enter n:")
n_input.pack()

int1 = IntVar()
int2 = IntVar()
int3 = IntVar()

form = StringVar()
form.set('(%s + %s)^%s' % (int1, int2, int3))

def update_form():
    number1 = a_input.number.get()
    number2 = b_input.number.get()
    number3 = n_input.number.get()
    int1.set(number1)
    int2.set(number2)
    int3.set(number3)
    a_input.number.delete(0, END)
    b_input.number.delete(0, END)
    n_input.number.delete(0, END)

Button(app, text = "Contine", command = update_form).pack(pady = 10)

Label(app, relief = SUNKEN, textvariable = form).pack(padx = 10, pady = 5, side = "bottom")

app.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure why the Label at the end of the program before the mainloop, does not update as I feel my logic is correct. I am new to programming, so it may just be a silly mistake.

Comment: I believe it's pretty standard to wrap your application in it's own class.  When you do that all components are easily accessible internal to the class.  Check out the example here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/minimal-app.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `form.set(...)` every time you want the label to change. It's not going to automatically change just because you change the variables  used to define its initial value.

Comment: When I add form.set('(%s + %s)^%s' % (int1, int2, int3)) to the update_form function, I still get the same output of >(PY_VAR0 + PY_VAR1)^PYVAR2  Why is this?

Comment: @Kage93: I don't know. Try adding print statements to see what the values of int1, int2 and int3.

Comment: They are still: PY_VAR0
PY_VAR1
PY_VAR2

Comment: You need to use `int1.get()` rather than `int1` in your format statements. `PY_VAR0` is the _name_ of the widget but you want to use the _value_ instead.